# Selected values from database only once even if they are duplicated

Tags: php, mysql, web

I am developing a web app of movies which contains crew members plus their roles, in crew member profile their is section which shows movies that he has already participated , but they should only be movies that is in the database , and movies there are fetched from roles since in roles table from my web app database there are columns called person as crew member and movie and role, so it may happen that a single crew member has more than one role in a single, so on his profile the same movie may be fetched more than one just because it appeared multiple times with that crew member person.

Here are sample codes .

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['cast']) && $_GET['cast'] !=''){
    $fullname = $_GET['cast'];
    $sqi2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM roles,movies
    WHERE roles.person = '$fullname' AND roles.movie = movies.title GROUP BY roles.movie");
?>
    <img src="<?=$movie['cover']?>" class="img-responsive">
                <a href="movie-profile.php?movie=<?=$movie['title'];?>"><?=$movie['title']?></a>
```

Comment: use `SELECT DISTINCT *`

Comment: Can you provide sample data? You also should use parameterized queries, this is open to SQL injections as is. I also prefer the defined `join`, use the `where` for limiting data and use `on`s for how the data should be joined.

Comment: You haven't provided enough info to really put this into an answer but I think you're looking for [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Also, speed may become an issue if you keep using `FROM roles, movies`. Try using an explicit `JOIN` statement instead (for example `FROM roles r JOIN movies m ON r.movie = m.movie`